# Gallery video thumbnails load extremely slow in android recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-gallery

I am trying to display all user video thumbnails from local gallery in recyclerview but it loads thumbnails very slow (it takes almost 10 seconds to load all video thumbnails). Code provided below:

VideoGalleryAdapter.java:

```
    public class VideoGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoGalleryAdapter.viewHolder> {

    public OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<VideoGalleryModel> videoArrayList;

    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VideoGalleryModel> videoArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.videoArrayList = videoArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoGalleryAdapter.viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoGalleryAdapter.viewHolder holder, final int i) {
        holder.videoDuration.setText(videoArrayList.get(i).getVideoDuration());
        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(videoArrayList.get(i).getVideoThumb()).into(holder.videoThumb);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoArrayList.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int pos, View v);
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView videoDuration;
        ImageView videoThumb;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            videoDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoDuration);
            videoThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoThumb);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

AddVideoActivity.java:

```
    public class AddVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int PERMISSION_READ = 0;
    public static ArrayList<VideoGalleryModel> videoArrayList;
    RecyclerView videoGalleryRV;
    ImageButton backBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_video);

        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        if (checkPermission()) {
            videoList();
        }
    }

    public void videoList() {
        videoGalleryRV = findViewById(R.id.videoGalleryRV);
        videoGalleryRV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        videoGalleryRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        videoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getVideos();
    }

    //get video files from storage
    public void getVideos() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(data, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

                VideoGalleryModel videoModel = new VideoGalleryModel();

                videoModel.setVideoThumb(bmp);
                videoModel.setVideoUri(Uri.parse(data));
                videoModel.setVideoDuration(timeConversion(Long.parseLong(duration)));
                videoArrayList.add(videoModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        VideoGalleryAdapter videoGalleryAdapter = new VideoGalleryAdapter(this, videoArrayList);
        videoGalleryRV.setAdapter(videoGalleryAdapter);

        videoGalleryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new VideoGalleryAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos, View v) {
                Toast.makeText(AddVideoActivity.this, "Video Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //time conversion
    public String timeConversion(long value) {
        String videoTime;
        int dur = (int) value;
        int hrs = (dur / 3600000);
        int mns = (dur / 60000) % 60000;
        int scs = dur % 60000 / 1000;

        if (hrs > 0) {
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hrs, mns, scs);
        } else {
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", mns, scs);
        }
        return videoTime;
    }

    //runtime storage permission
    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if ((READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_READ);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_READ) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    videoList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_add_video.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddVideoActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            android:tint="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/backBtn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gilroymedium"
            android:text="Choose video"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/headerDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerContainer"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/videoGalleryRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerDivider"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

VideoGalleryModel.java:

```
public class VideoGalleryModel {

    Bitmap videoThumb;
    String videoDuration;
    Uri videoUri;

    public Bitmap getVideoThumb() {
        return videoThumb;
    }

    public void setVideoThumb(Bitmap videoThumb) {
        this.videoThumb = videoThumb;
    }

    public String getVideoDuration() {
        return videoDuration;
    }

    public void setVideoDuration(String videoDuration) {
        this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
    }

    public Uri getVideoUri() {
        return videoUri;
    }

    public void setVideoUri(Uri videoUri) {
        this.videoUri = videoUri;
    }
}
```

video_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainVideoContainer"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlackTransparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videoThumb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:06"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gilroysemibold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to know the proper way to show video thumbnail in recyclerview and how to load it faster. If you have additional questions ask me and I will be happy to answer it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Glide can load a video thumbnail by uri.

Comment: Can you share video_list & VideoGalleryModel also

Comment: @KishanMaurya I added them to my question sir you can check it

Comment: Any specific reason to create video thumbnail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since creating a video thumbnail is a heavy operation. So this is taking time.
Try commenting these lines

```
//Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(data, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
 //videoModel.setVideoThumb(bmp);
```

and load image thumbnail directly using Glide

```
Glide.with(context).load(new File(videoArrayList.get(i).videoUri.toString())).into(holder.videoThumb);
```

Comment: thank you sir. I tried Glide.with(context).load(new File(videoArrayList.get(i).getVideoUri().toString())).into(holder.videoThumb); and it works (with slight delay but certainly better than before)

Comment: You can avoid bitmap creation as well. since you are now, not using this bitmap, so can be avoided too. This will save a lot of time.